# How to enable mapping only if there is no quickfix window opened in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like do disable following mapping when I open quickfix window.

```
map <F5> :ZoomWin<cr>
```

Comment: You seem to have *many* issues with that plugin. Did you consider the possibility that it is not what you actually need?

Comment: But i did find any alternative plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean quickfix? If so, there are three ways:

1. Use `<expr>` mappings:

   ```
   nnoremap <expr> <F5> (&buftype is# "quickfix" ? "" : ":\<C-u>ZoomWin\n")
   ```
2. Use BufEnter event to set/restore mapping:

   ```
   augroup F5Map
       autocmd! BufEnter * :if &buftype is# 'quickfix' | nunmap <F5> | else | nnoremap <F5> :<C-u>ZoomWin<CR> | endif
   augroup END
   ```
3. Create mapping locally only for buffers where it is needed:

   ```
   augroup F5Map
       autocmd! BufEnter * :if &buftype isnot# 'quickfix' && empty(maparg('<F5>')) | nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :<C-u>ZoomWin<CR> | endif
   augroup END
   ```

**Update**: to disable mapping when any of the opened windows contains quickfix buffer use the following:

```
nnoremap <expr> <F5> (&buftype is# "quickfix" || empty(filter(tabpagebuflist(), 'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") is# "quickfix"')) ? ":\<C-u>ZoomWin\n" : "")
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable like above nunmap <F5> but even when one of three panes is quickfix and active pane is not quickfix?

Comment: @regedarek Replace `&buftype is# 'quickfix'` condition with `!empty(filter(tabpagebuflist(), 'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") is# "quickfix"'))` in fist variant. Don’t use second with `nunmap` or third one.

Comment: @regedarek I was inaccurate: use `&buftype isnot# "quickfix" && !empty(…)` (`&buftype is# "quickfix" || empty(…)` in the variant I posted in update) for “and active pane is not quickfix”.